# How to send message to a Slack channel in Python

Tags: python, chat, slack

I need to send out message to a Slack channel with Python.

My Google search ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20%2B%20slack%20send%20message&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=d1w&ei=kNhMYqWNLJW_3LUP1_a_qA0&ved=0ahUKEwillZmckf72AhWVH7cAHVf7D9UQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=python%20%2B%20slack%20send%20message&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOggIABAIEA0QHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFC0DVi5FGDqFWgCcAF4AIABjQGIAf8FkgEDMy40mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)) and search from Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20send%20message%20to%20a%20Slack%20channel%20in%20Python)) results in little help. What is the right way to get it working?

The closest guide I found is from Slack official guide [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending#getting_started) but it's *not* clear how to do the authentication with `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` to call `client.chat_postMessage()`

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient
client = WebClient(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))

result = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel=channel_id,
    text="Hello world!"
)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"how to do the authentication"*? Just set the env var, the code shows how it gets used.

Comment: What value to set? @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean by _"What value"_? There's only one env var being used in the code you've shown... Have you looked at the [relevant SDK docs](https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/index.html)?

Comment: From your link, where exactly the line saying where to get the env var value?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the token in the first place? Because the Slack docs you've already linked to walk step by step through that.

Comment: Where exactly it is showed how to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In brief**

- create Slack app aka myslackchat [ref](https://api.slack.com/start/overview#creating)
- grant scope `chat:write` to Slack app [ref](https://api.slack.com/apps)
- get Slack channel id aka `channel id`
- get `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` of your Slack app
- add Slack app `myslackchat` to your Slack workspace, and 2nd, add `myslackchat` to Slack channel `channel id`
- python code to send message to `channel id`, with `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN`  [ref](https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending#publishing)

p.s.

How to get

After days seeking Slack documentation for it, here is related [guide](https://api.slack.com/apps/A039UDCTV47/oauth?); please search the page to get to this section `OAuth Tokens for Your Workspace` - this is a pain. I have no idea why there is no SLACK_BOT_TOKEN mentioned in this guide.

[image]

---

Full details:

One thing you'll need before starting is a Slack app. If you don't have one yet, here's a very [quick guide to help you create one](https://api.slack.com/start/overview#creating).

Requesting the necessary permissions `chat:write`. This one grants permission for your app to send messages as itself (apps can send messages as users or bot users)

Requesting these permissions is easy:

- Load up the settings for your app from the app management page.
- In the navigation menu, choose the `OAuth & Permissions` feature.
- Scroll down to the Scopes section, and pick channels:read and chat:write from the drop down menu.
- Click save changes.
- Scroll back to the top of this page and look for the button that says Install App to Workspace (or Reinstall App if you've done this before). Click it.